# asp.net SSO and SAML from WebApi simply because that is all the client has

Tags: asp.net, mobile, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, saml

I have inherited this and am stuck with this approach. I am just trying to figure out if it will in fact work.

The project involves your standard asp.net web api application with android and ios clients. The trick is with the authentication. The application is for a 3rd party, and the only way that the user can be authenticated from the outside world is by using their IDP. The 3rd party does not care what happens after the user is authenticated.
All I have to go by is the architecture diagram that the former team members created. The diagram has 3 layers. User/Mobile Device, SAML SP Web APP and Client IDP. The important part of the flow is as follows:

1. Mobile App calls SAML SP Web App with the IDP user name and password.
2. SAML Web App calls the IDP login using the user's credentials
3. User Authenticated ? Responds to SAML SP Web App with success and SAML Assertion/Token
4. SAML SP Web App responds to mobile App with approved message

Once the user is authenticated through the IDP, the plan was then to issue a bearer token to the mobile device.

Unless things have changed a lot since I last had to play with SAML (2011), it seems I am missing a client browser to redirect from the SP to the IDP and then redirect back to the SP when a valid SAMl assertion is created.

Am I missing something here, such as a way to emulate a browser to allow for these redirects and plugging in the correct user name and password, or is there a way to call the IDP directly from the SP and have it issue a response directly back to the SP? Or am I just reading the diagram wrong or inheriting some very bad assumptions? I'm in the awkward position where I don't want to go back to the client and revisit a process that was supposedly decided upon at the start of the year unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Stupid question may be, but what does SP and IDP mean?

Comment: @venerik SP = Service Provider, which is SAML lingo for "web application". Idp = Identity Provider, the login server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things don't change a lot with SAML, so your knowledge from 2011 is still definitely valid.

I'm also missing the browser redirect step. It is a quite common misunderstanding that the SP can send username/password to the Idp and get an assertion back, but that is not supported by the SAML WebSSO Profile (which is the one that's actually used).

Using SAML2 for a mobile application is hard, there's no good support in the SAML2 protocol for redirecting back to the client. A common way to work around it is to use OpenID Connect. I've been involved in setups where the mobile client authenticates to IdentityServer3 via OpenID Connect. Then IdentityServer3 acts as a SAML2 SP (through the Kentor.AuthServices middleware) to the upstream SAML2 Idp.

I understand that you are in a delicate situation but I think that you have to go back and ask how it is supposed to work. Specifically you should ask where the user is supposed to enter credentials and how the communication between the SP and Idp is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you Anders. Yes, there  seemed to have been a misunderstanding that an assertion could be sent back directly to the SP at one point, and the documentation was never updated. I finally have all that cleared up (only took 3 days.) I have to address both the mobile apps and an Mvc admin component. I am marking this as correct to thank you for restoring my sanity and for your suggestions with mobile support.